# Is possible to use a component as mat-grid-tile in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, scss-mixins

I'm learning the use of angular material for a real life application and right now I'm stuck.

So... I have a route `localhost:4200/admin/home` which obviously call the associated component, in this case AdminHomeComponent

AdminHomeComponent is a dashboard. To be clear, I'm not asking how to build a dashboard. I am looking for a specific aspect of the `<mat-grid-list></mat-grid-list>`. My idea  of component is: every item of the dashboard is a component. So... todo, tasks, ecc.

I tryed to make something like that:

```
<mat-grid-list>
   <app-todo></app-todo>
   <app-tasks></app-tasks>
</mat-grid-list>
```

In my conception has absolutely sense the component self-define his columns and rows.

**But that doesn't works!**

Otherwise, this, instead, works (but a bit non-sense to me):

```
<mat-grid-list ...>

  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
            <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                    <app-todo></app-todo>
           </mat-card-content>
   </mat-card>

  </mat-grid-tile>

  (... another tiles)

</mat-grid-list>
```

There's some way to use `<mat-grid-list>` where every `<mat-grid-tile>` be a specific component (as my first attempt)?

The component is rendered rightly, but with  a `<div>` and `<app-todo>` childs between `<mat-grid-list>` and `<mat-grid-tile>`, what does it invisible, so I am pretty sure the problem is the strict css rule.

Comment: Probably, a bit off-topic. If you want a dashboard layout, then try out [Angular Gridster2](https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/). Its quite good.

Comment: Well... it's a opinion. Yes, could or I could to build my own, manually, but material brings a dashboard schematics and I want to make use of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juninho, The mat-grid-list need mat-grid-tile, but you can use as content of mat-grid-tile any thing

```
<mat-grid-list>
   <mat-grid-tile>
     <app-todo></app-todo>
   </mat-grid-tile>
   <mat-grid-tile>
      <app-tasks></app-tasks>
   </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

A [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxs42n?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: Yep :'( I realized that. The element is rendered, but with <div> and <app-todo> childs between <mat-grid-list> and <mat-grid-tile>, so I am pretty sure the problem is the strict css rule. With some scss to fix, maybe